# Calibrating videre stereo camera

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use the camera calibration package of ros to calibrate the videre stereo camera.The drivers of this stereo camera are from the videre_stereo_cam(ua_ros_pkg).When i tried to calibrate the camera using camera_calibration package it said that there were no services that are required to run the package.[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/1802/how-to-calibrate-videre_stereo_camera).So i used the --no-service-check option and then ran the camera calibration package but it is unable to commit the values.it is giving the following errors.

traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/srik/ros/diamondback/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 213, in on_mouse

```
if self.do_upload():
```

File "/home/srik/ros/diamondback/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 184, in do_upload

```
response = self.set_left_camera_info_service(info[0])
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 418, in **call**

```
return self.call(*args, **kwds)
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 477, in call

```
service_uri = self._get_service_uri(request)
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 445, in _get_service_uri

```
raise ServiceException("service [%s] unavailable"%self.resolved_name)
```

rospy.service.ServiceException: service [/stereo/left/set_camera_info] unavailable

From this i understood that due to the lack of those services it is not able to commit the values.Is there any other method to commit the values. Did anyone use this camera calibration package to calibrate videre stereo camera.If so please help me how to proceed from here.Thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10953/calibrating-videre-stereo-camera/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

videre_stereo_cam package does not expose services that allow you to store calibration information on camera. The only reason they are not there is because we did not have a need to calibrate a camera since they came factory calibrated and worked well for us. There are methods that deal with parsing and creating calibration information of which I only used the parsing part (see [stereoimage.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ua-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/arrg/ua_drivers/videre_stereo_cam/src/videre_stereo_cam/stereoimage.cpp) file towards the end of the file). I would think it should be fairly simple to add those services and I would certainly accept a patch if you end up implementing those (I could also help with development if you are willing to test).

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2